# How to solve floodwait error await result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
[12:36:26] Joining @acharaexchange...
ERROR:telethon.client.updates:Unhandled exception on join_start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/yul/msg2/telethon/client/updates.py", line 284, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "join.py", line 83, in join_start
    await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_name))
  File "/storage/emulated/0/yul/msg2/telethon/client/users.py", line 48, in __call__
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 205 seconds is required
```

Anyone can help me how to solve it i want to make this if that case appeared , how to make it being restart or make time sleep and continue automatically

My script like this

## Join the channel

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=dogeclick_channel, incoming=True))
async def join_start(event):
    message = event.raw_text
    if 'You must join' in message:  
        channel_name = re.search(r'You must join @(.*?) to earn', message).group(1)
        print_msg_time(f'Joining @{channel_name}...')

        # joining
        await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_name))
        print_msg_time(f'Verifying...')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
async def join_start(event):
    if True :
        try:
            message = event.raw_text
            if 'You must join' in message:  
                channel_name = re.search(r'You must join @(.*?) to earn', message).group(1)
                print_msg_time(f'Joining @{channel_name}...')
                hidden = random. randrange(20, 45)
                print_msg_time('Sending /join command')
                time.sleep(hidden)
                await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_name))
                # Join the channel
                print_msg_time(f'Verifying...')
                
                # Clicks the joined
                await client(GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(
                    peer=url_channel,
                    msg_id=event.message.id,
                    data=event.message.reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[1].data
                ))
        except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
            print('Flood wait for ', e.seconds)
            exit
```